# Css. How to move div with fixed position up if it overlays footer

Tags: css, overlay, fixed

I have a menu, content and footer. Menu has fixed position. If I scroll it down to the end of page it becomes to overlay the footer. How can I force menu to move up if it starts to overlay the footer?

[image]

**EDIT:**
I use bootstrap classes.
My Html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="myScrollspy">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
                 ...
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div id="section1">    
                <h1>Section 1</h1>
                <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="section2"> 
                <h1>Section 2</h1>
                <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
            </div>
            ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
ul.nav-pills {
      position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: actually I used an example from  http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the bootstrap "**affix**" plugin.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

You can see an example here of how it works in combination with the scrollspy.
http://codepen.io/SitePoint/full/GgOzwX/ (Not my code)

Essentially what you do is tell it when to start and stop being a 'fixed' element.

```
$('#nav').affix({
    offset: {     
      top: $('#nav').offset().top,
      bottom: ($('footer').outerHeight(true) + $('.application').outerHeight(true)) + 40
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change menu, content and footer to block.

add css :

```
.clearfix::before, .clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix::after {
    clear: both;
}
```

and add class `clearfix` to your footer (highest hierarchy) and to class `container`.